# How can I get two <div>'s closer together?

Tags: html, css

[image]See image attached - I want to bring the 'left' and 'right' 's closer together so they remain as close as both are to the header, in blue above.

this is my CSS for both left and right 's ... thank's a lot!

```
.left {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #DDFF00;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 10%;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFE6E6;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 88%;
}
```

Comment: Change `width: 88%;` to `width: 89%;` in `.right`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.left {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #DDFF00;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 10%;
}

.right {
    float: right; /*<-change to left */
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFE6E6;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px; /*<-and play with that too*/
    height: 500px;
    width: 88%; /*<-or increase that, without any changes above */
}
```